# Remove square brackets at beginning and ending using Undersore or Javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I trying to remove array square bracket at beginning and end.

EX: [['moe', 30], ['larry', 40], ['curly', 50]]

Need: ['moe', 30], ['larry', 40], ['curly', 50]

Comment: Is that really a string or rather a nested array? Please add your code.

Comment: I created one excel file for api url access(nodejs project).Then i got excel file data in array of array.
Ex: data = [['DomainURL',Api URL','TFS URL'],['http://abc.us/','http://zzz.us/','http://dec.us/']]

I want to need result: 
['DomainURL',Api URL','TFS URL'],['http://abc.us/','http://zzz.us/','http://dec.us/']

Answer (score 2):

If it is a string you can use the `substring` or `slice` method like this:

```js
var yourString = "[['moe', 30], ['larry', 40], ['curly', 50]]";
// using substring
var result = yourString.substring(1, yourString.length-1);
console.log(result);
// using slice
var result2 = yourString.slice(1, -1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Hi Tobi, How to remove " "(double quotes)
EX: ['moe', 30], ['larry', 40], ['curly', 50]

Comment: I am getting result
"['moe', 30], ['larry', 40], ['curly', 50]"
so how to remove " "(double quotes)

Comment: I am getting string value only

Comment: There are no double quotes, where do you get double quotes?

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.