# how to remove String Quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to remove string Quotes mark but cant able to remove.

Ex: `['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50]`

Need: `['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50]`

Because I'm trying Underscore Object function(_.object).

Ex: `_.object("['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50]")`

Only I am getting undefined result.

Comment: Is it just a string? `string.replace(/"/g, '')` will do it if so

Comment: You should learn about types first. Your question does not really make sense and you already asked a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895931/remove-square-brackets-at-beginning-and-ending-using-undersore-or-javascript).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to remove double quotes from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove double quotes, you can do it like this:

```js
const quotes = "['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50]";

const noQuotes = quotes.replace(/\"/, '');
console.log(noQuotes);
```

`/\"/` is a regular expression that matches any `"` in the string. You simply replace them with the empty string.

Comment: I trying underscore function but its not working
EX: _.object(noQuotes);
getting only undefined

Comment: var quotes = "['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50]";
var noQuotes = quotes.replace(/\"/, '');
_.object(noQuotes)

I am getting only "Undefined"